# harmonic forms with respect to different metrics

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, hodge-theory

Given a smooth manifold M with two different metric, we can consider U and V, the spaces of harmonic k-forms on M with respect to the first metric and second metric respectively. The question is whether the projection map from U to V an isomorphism?

Thanks.

Comment: Projection map?

Comment: Presumably Eric means the projection map with respect to the L^2 inner product on forms induced by (say) the second metric.  The harmonic forms with respect to the first metric are a subspace of all forms, and one can ask if they project isomorphically.

Answer (score 3):

If your manifold is closed, then this is true for the $L^2$ projection (in either metric), since the (finite dimensional) space of harmonic forms is the $L^2$ orthogonal of exact forms inside the space of closed forms, hence any other complement vector space (for the same pair) projects isomorphically.